# Managing and storing data of facebook friends with xcode and facebook API

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, facebook, mobile

Here is the context. I have a class in my project that represents a trophy. Trophies objects are loaded from Core Data and are local to the application. In a view controller, the user sees the list of trophies and can modify/create new ones. Now I need to add facebook functionality in those trophies. Ideally in that list of trophies (which is a tableview with one section) you would see the trophies of your friends when logged in. Something similar is done in the paid version of Map my Run app, in which you can see your facebook friends' planned tracks.

I'm fairly new to Xcode development and never touched the facebook API. From what I've seen, there isn't any real remote storage for a facebook app (there was a data storage API that was deprecated in 2010 from what I've read). There's this thing called the Open Graph API, which lets you create and manage objects that you use in your app, but from what I understand it does not support mobile yet and can only be used in web apps (and I'm not sure if that's what I'm looking for).

So my question is, what is the structure of an app that implements such a functionality? I've searched samples, examples and tutorials but I've not seen anything regarding this specification. All I've seen are stuff like posting/share an image, link, etc. to your profile.

My first guess would be to create my own database (since right now they are handled locally with Core Data) and upload trophies people would like to share to it and attach the facebook userID in a column of that trophy table and then load the trophies that match the userID of their friends. Is there something in the API I've missed that can handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your trophies aren’t objects in the facebook graph but you’re managing them yourself, then it would be the easiest way to save people’s facebook id when giving them a trophy.

Then you query the graph api for /me/friends, to get a user’s friends FB ids – and then just intersect that list with the list of your awarded trophies by FB id.

Comment: Thank you for replying :) I figure this is what I will have to do. But I would like a precision regarding this sentence "If your trophies aren’t objects in the facebook graph". You can't create your own objects in the facebook graph, right (without Open Graph)? If I understand correctly, it's not possible to create a trophy list object with a connection to trophies objects, and connect that list to a facebook user.

Comment: No, you can’t store your own data on FB servers. All you could do with Open Graph objects is have users perform certain actions on them – so maybe you could go with an object ’trophy’ and have an action ’earn’ connected to it. Then you could publish these actions to FB via your app – but your basic data storage of who earned what trophy you’d still have to do yourself to be able to work with it in a reasonable way.